# Pokemon Play It freezes on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, pokemon-play-it

I originally downloaded a version of the game Pokemon Play it! v2 from the internet (I thought it  was old enough that trying to find a disc would be too much trouble). Anyway, upon downloading it on the Windows XP computer and playing, it suddenly froze halfway through the first tutorial gym (the name for the levels). It just sat there repeating the last word over and over again, and not responding to any of the controls.

The freeze was so bad that none of the keyboard's buttons would work, so the only way I was able to get out of the program was a hard reset via the computer power button. I tried the game a few more times (about 6) but only got the same result. The interesting thing was that everything else on the game worked, such as credits, collection, etc. Only playing the first level caused it to freeze. I finally resigned to the fact that this must be because it was a copy of the game downloaded off the internet and who knows what's happened to it.

So I went on Amazon and found copies of the game are actually not that expensive, and bought one. When the disc came I ran the install software in compatibility mode and then played the game. But to my surprise, it still caused the exact same freeze! I went and tried the disc on my Windows 7, and the game ran fine!

**TL;DR:** *I bought Pokemon Play It! v2 but it freezes on my Windows XP system when I play the levels. It does not freeze on my Windows 7 computer.* I know this question is pretty general, but could anyone help solve this?

Comment: Assuming both systems run on different hardware: I'm guessing your Windows 7 PC is simply much more powerful than your XP one. Assuming you were using compatibility mode on XP, but not on 7: That may be the reason why XP was slower. As it stands now, we don't have enough information to give you a fully fledged answer.

Comment: I used compatibilty mode on both computers. The Windows XP I have has run tons of game discs fine for years (I think there's something like 30+ installed on there, as well as some MS-DOS games).

Unfortunatly, I have no more information to offer on the problem. I was posting just in case someone had encountered the same or a similar problem and knew how to fix it or was able to identify what's wrong by the info I gave.